# How do I trigger an action when the user has hit enter?

Tags: android, triggers, android-edittext

If (in Android) I have an EditText box, how can I trigger an event when the user has finished entering data and hits return/Next?

I have tried using the code below but it seems to have no effect. I also get an 'The method onEditorAction(EditText, int, KeyEvent) from the type new extView.OnEditorActionListener(){} is never used locally' error.

```
myEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
            public boolean onEditorAction(EditText v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT)
                {
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I played around a bit with various things and found that the code below works:

```
myEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {                     
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        // Do some stuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe you want is the `setOnEditorActionListener()` method, [dev guide info here on the method.](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setOnEditorActionListener%28android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener%29)

Comment: Interessting method. Never came accross this one... Will keep it in mind.

Comment: @DrColossos More related info about it by @CommonsWare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489852/android-handle-enter-in-an-edittext/1489895#1489895

Comment: Thanks. Would that also work if someone clicked on the EditText and then clicked away. Possibly handled by a loss of focus command?

Comment: loss of focus is too unreliable..many times I run into a edittext box that won't lose focus after hitting enter.

Answer (score 3):

Add a KeyListener to the textbox that listens key events. Within the key event, listen  to the "ENTER" key pressed and perform your action.

You can find something similar here: [Android Development: How To Use onKeyUp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741147/android-development-how-to-use-onkeyup) and in the docs for [UI-Events](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html).

A good example is in the linked SO question. Following this, you should get the desired result.

Comment: As specified in the Android documentation, the default software keyboard will never send any key event to any application targeting Jelly Bean or later, and will only send events for some presses of the delete and return keys to applications targeting Ice Cream Sandwich or earlier.