# how to start an activity automtically when user input a value to textfield in android(Like keyup event.)?

Tags: android, native

i want to enter a value to a text field and once i enter i want it to view something on a text view automatically.. how to do that in android.?? 
this is what i tried.

txt.setKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

```
        @Override
        public boolean onKeyUp(View v, Editable e, int i, KeyEvent k) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(i==40)
            {
                TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                tv.setText("Done");
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: "once i enter i want it to view something on a text view automatically" means?

Comment: Use debugger or logging to check if `onKeyUp()` is called and with which parameters (especially which `i`)

Answer (score 0):

Take your input value in an EditText. Compare your EditText's value and accordingly change your TextView. I don't see any use of onKeyUp method.

Or if you really want to use onKeyUp method, I guess [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741147/android-development-how-to-use-onkeyup) link might help you!