# EditText needs to change color listener

Tags: java, android

hey this is my code i need some help please when the user enter his user id the edit text needs to go from red to green the code is working but only if you enter your user id and then press enter i need it  to automatically change color.

```
editText1_id.Setontextchanged(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (editText1_id.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," Please insert your User ID", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if ((editText1_id.length() < 4)){
                makeToastLogin("Please insert your User ID");
            } else {
                userId = editText1_id.getText().toString();
            }
            if (editText1_id.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                editText1_id.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonshap_red_outline);
            }else if (editText1_id.length() < 4){
                editText1_id.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonshap_red_outline);
            }else if (editText1_id.length() == 4) {
                editText1_id.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.insert_frame);
            } else {
                editText1_id.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.insert_frame);
            }

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can put your code inside `TextWatcher` like this:

```
editText1_id.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (editText1_id.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                editText1_id.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonshap_red_outline);
            }else if (editText1_id.length() < 4){
                editText1_id.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonshap_red_outline);
            }else if (editText1_id.length() == 4) {
                editText1_id.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.insert_frame);
            } else {
                editText1_id.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.insert_frame);
            }
        }
    });
```

as you can see you can add `addTextChangedListener` to each `EditText`. it has three listener that help you to notice when user start typing

Comment: Thanks MHP, I don't know what i would have done with out your help, thank your for your support. its highly appreciated.

Comment: @johan glad to help you . if this answer helped you please mark it as accepted answer for other to understand it.

Comment: no,just to each EditText instance can addTextChangedListener.what you . want do for button? ask it in other question

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an OnClickListener, you need a TextWatcher.
See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11134227/3673616

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you're trying to do this, except instead of 2 you want 4: [Android Development: How To Use onKeyUp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741147/android-development-how-to-use-onkeyup)